# How to declare and access tuple of two elements in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am creating a stored procedure on Bigquery which receives a table name as an input and checks the `information_schema.COLUMNS` table to get its column names & datatypes.

In my case, I am trying to loop thru each column and its datatype, check if the type is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, change that column from `COLNAME` to `CAST(COLNAME AS TIMESTAMP/DATETIME) as COLNAME`.
I am concatenating each of the column's result into a string which will finally look like a select query on the table received from arguments.
To do the activity, I wrote the below store procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `projectid`.datasetname.conversion (tablename String, stagingdb String, basedb String)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columnDatatypes ARRAY<STRING, STRING>;
    DECLARE resultuantColumns STRING;
    DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
        "select column_name, data_type from default_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=`"||tablename||"`"
    ) INTO columnDatatypes;
    WHILE i < ARRAY_LENGTH(primarykey) DO
        IF(i = ARRAY_LENGTH(primarykey)-1) THEN
            IF columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] == "TIMESTAMP" THEN
                SET resultuantColumns = resultuantColumns || "CAST(" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 0] || " as TIMESTAMP) as "" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1];
                SET i = i + 1;
                ELSEIF columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] == "DATETIME" THEN
                    SET resultuantColumns = resultuantColumns || "CAST(" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 0] || " as DATETIME) as "" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1];
                    SET i = i + 1;
                ELSE
                    SET resultuantColumns = resultuantColumns || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 0];
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] == "TIMESTAMP" THEN
                SET resultuantColumns = resultuantColumns || "CAST(" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 0] || " as TIMESTAMP) as "" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] || ", ";
                SET i = i + 1;
                ELSEIF columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] == "DATETIME"  THEN
                    SET resultuantColumns = resultuantColumns || "CAST(" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 0] || " as DATETIME) as "" || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] || ", ";
                    SET i = i + 1;
                ELSE
                    SET resultuantColumns = resultuantColumns || columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 0] || ", ";
                    SET i = i + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
        """INSERT INTO `projectid.datasetname.tablename` VALUES ( """ || resultuantColumns || ");";
    );
    END;
```

I declared a tuple `columnDatatypes ARRAY<STRING, STRING>` to hold the resultant of the select query because it is returning two columns: `column_name` & `data_type`.

The problem here is I am facing an error at the line of declaring a tuple of two elements:

> DECLARE columnDatatypes ARRAY<STRING, STRING>;
> Error: Syntax error: Expected ">" but got "," at [3:41]

And while I am looping thru the array, I see another error in the WHILE loops second IF condition when accessing the elements of the array based on its offset.

```
WHILE i < ARRAY_LENGTH(primarykey) DO
        IF(i = ARRAY_LENGTH(primarykey)-1) THEN
            IF columnDatatypes[OFFSET(i), 1] == "TIMESTAMP" THEN
```

> Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "]" at [11:40] in the IF condition above (Error from the above line)

I tried different syntaxes for creating tuples as below:

```
DECLARE columnDatatypes ARRAY<<STRING, STRING>>;
DECLARE columnDatatypes ARRAY<<STRING>, <STRING>>;
```

All of them are saying syntax error.
I searched Google's GCP documentation here but there is not reference for tuple declaration and accessing tht elements in them.
Is there any datatype in Bigquery that I can use as a Tuple and access its element by Index position ?

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it ?

Comment: you shouldn't be treating SQL as python. There is lots of things that are wrong here. Starting with double equal sign and  ending on the way you trying to build your final query. There are no tuples here, but there is work around it (concat of column name and type)